# Redis server log file rotation on Windows

Tags: windows, caching, logging, redis

We are using Redis 3.2 (64 bit) (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, for in-memory data caching.

Have been able to write redis-server logs by setting the logfile parameter in redis.conf file but, could not specify log file max size & subsequent rollover. 
Would want to know whether there is a way to specify log file rotation in Redis conf / probably pass that as a parameter when starting the Redis server daemon process.

It would really help to get any suggestions on this front.

Thanks & regards,
Surjit

Comment: According to the annotation information of Redis offical configuration file, there are not any configuration variables which can be specify log file max size & subsequent rollover, although this can be achieved with an alternative. Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3ca1a34b-3617-48a7-9d7c-a7cd8b4ec2ec/redis-server-log-file-rotation-on-windows?forum=opensourcedevwithazure

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question... MS Open Tech Redis project has been abandoned.

You can checkout Memurai, which derives from it [link](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3).

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.